# Proving that a projection is a dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem:

- Projection $\langle ,\rangle: \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by formula $\langle u ,v \rangle=u^TAv$ , where $A$ is a symetric matrix $2\times 2$. Prove that $\langle ,\rangle$ is a dot product on $\mathbb{R^2}$ iff $a_{11}>0$ and det$(A)>0$.

My work so far:

We have been given a definition of dot product so I stuck to it - I have already proved that:

1. $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle v,u \rangle$
2. $\langle u$a$,v\rangle=a\langle u,v\rangle$
3. $\langle u,v+w\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle+\langle u,w\rangle$
   .

The last point (4.) of the definition is that $\langle u,u\rangle>0$ if $u\neq$ **0**. I am having problems with the last point. Let's have $A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\
b&d \end{pmatrix}$. Det$(A)=ad-b^2>0$. Then $ad>b^2$ and therefore $d>0$ (because $a>0$ and $b^2>0$). Let's have $u=(x_1,x_2)^T$.

Then, when I replace $u,A$ in the formula of the projection, I get $\langle u ,u \rangle=u^TAu=(x_1, x_2)\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ b&d \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=ax_1^2+2bx_1x_2+dx_2^2$.

I need to prove that $ax_1^2+2bx_1x_2+dx_2^2>0$ if $x_1\neq0$ and $x_2\neq0$ (and knowing that $a>0, d>0$ and $ad>b^2$).

Do you have any ideas? Or if it is possible to prove it any other way.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D:=\det(A)=ad-b^2>0$. Then $ad=D+b^2$ and 
\begin{align*}
d(ax_1^2+2bx_1x_2+dx_2^2)&=adx_1^2+2bdx_1x_2+d^2x_2^2 \\&=(D+b^2)x_1^2+2bdx_1x_2+d^2x_2^2\\ &=Dx_1^2+b^2x_1^2+2bdx_1x_2+d^2x_2^2\\&=Dx_1^2+(bx_1+dx_2)^2\\ &>0
\end{align*} if $(x_1,x_2)\neq(0,0)$. Since $d>0$ the result follows by dividing by $d$.

---

For the converse note that if $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product, then \begin{align*}
ax_1^2+2bx_1x_2+dx_2^2>0,\qquad (x_1,x_2)\neq(0,0).
\end{align*}
For $(x_1,x_2)=(1,0)$ and $(x_1,x_2)=(0,1)$, this gives $a>0$ and $d>0$, respectively, and as above,
\begin{align*}
Dx_1^2+(bx_1+dx_2)^2>0,\qquad (x_1,x_2)\neq(0,0).
\end{align*}
With $(x_1,x_2)=(d,-b)$ this gives $Dd^2>0$ and therefore $D>0$.

Comment: And should I prove the other implication - if $\langle , \rangle$ is a dot product, then $a_{11}>0$ and det$(A)>0$? I can't find the solution - do you have any idea? Thx

Comment: Sry, I overlooked that you was also asking for the converse. I added this part, too.

Comment: thx, and by "I can't find the solution" I meant that I am not able to prove it, not that you forget it, hope I didn't offend you. I thought that I would manage to prove it by myself but I still have a lot to learn and this site (the people here) is brilliant. Thx

Comment: No you didn't offend me at all, don't worry :) I really overlooked this part, but I am glad that I could help. You are always very welcome.